# What's causing the weird light pink color splotch in this photo?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts

Can someone tell me what is causing the splotch in this photo? It;s like a pinkish color right in the middle. The day was cloudy. Sun wasn't out. This is only seen in two of the pictures that I have.

Do you think it has something to do with the lens, or do you think it's spirits (LOL)?

[image: pinkish pur color in photo]

I have a Nikon Coolpix S8000 14.2MP Digital Camera with 10x Optical Vibration Reduction (VR) Zoom.

Answer (score 3):

It is lens flare.

Many more examples as well as how to avoid lens flare, and why you might even desire lens flare can be found under the lens-flare tag, here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens-flare